# Linux' Screen terminates without errors

Tags: linux, bash, laravel, queue, gnu-screen

I use Linux [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) to run some PHP script:

```
screen -L php artisan queue:work sqs --daemon --env=production
```

But unfortunately there is some error (in queue:work) and after 5-10 minutes Screen terminates immediately when an error occur. I don't see any error in `screenlog.0`. And because Screen terminates, it 'disappear' and I'm unable to read any output of `php artisan queue:work`. How do I make screen 'not' hide when it terminates (or may be some alternative approach)?

Comment: `screen -L php .... 2>&1 > log.txt`? have the job dump all its output to file instead of the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

1. Run the `screen` command without any parameters
2. When the command starts, you will see a virtual terminal. Then run your command: `php artisan queue:work sqs --daemon --env=production`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.

Now when `php...` crashes, the screen command will be still running (what you can check by `screen -ls` and attach to the terminal by `screen -r terminal_id`. In my case, I see error `Segmentation Fault` and I change the command to: `php artisan queue:listen sqs --env=production` and now everything work good :)

Comment: how do i know what's current screen id?